# Angular/Html - How to make a whole cell clickable?

Tags: html, css, angular, html-table, routerlink

I have a table, and i want that each time someone clicks on a cell, it opens a new tab which leads on another route. I've managed to do it with a button in the cell, where my  element has a class "button", and is inside my  element, but it's not working when i remove the class button and want to make the whole cell clickable.

```
<td
 <a *ngIf="isClickable()" [routerLink]="['/', lang, 'toto']"
                          [queryParams]="this.detailParams(param1, param2)"
                          target="_blank"></a>
</td>
```

Any idea how to achieve that ? i want to keep the target blank for the tab, and the routerlink, etc.
I've already tried:

```
td a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
```

it doesn't change a thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use click on td instead of inner tag

Comment: i've edited a bit so that it's clearer, but as i said i want to keep the routerlink, not use a click

Comment: Ah a colleague found out a trick, adding a &nbsp; in the <a> tag :D it's solved, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should approach your problem. Using Angular (click) event in "td" tag instead of putting "a" in the cell. "a" in the cell only links your cell content and not the whole html tag.

```
<td (click)="yourFunction()"> Content </td>
```

If you want to use link on "td" tag you can do so by adding [routerLink].

```
<td [routerLink]="your_link"> Content </td>
```

Be ware because [routerLink] only works for routes inside your Angular application. You should use href and safe links if routing to external link.